# Rebuild Accumulo after namenode crash corrupts root block

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, accumulo

our development HDP cluster had a power outage that corrupted some HDFS system blocks used by Accumulo, now the cluster is in safemode and ambari won't restart.

Being a DEV box, HDFS has a replication factor of 1, so I can't restore the corrupted blocks.

What is the best way to rebuild Accumulo to cleanly to restore the HDFS filesystem, and bring the HDP cluster back up? There's no user data in accumulo to save, so a wipe and reinitialise would be fine in this case. Just not sure of the best way to do this.

Some corruption details:

`hdfs fsck / | egrep -v '^\.+$' | grep -v replica | grep -v Replica| grep "^\/" | grep "CORRUPT" | sed 's/: CORRUPT.*//' | grep -v "^$"`

output is:

```
Connecting to namenode via http://xyz.fakedomain.com:50070/fsck?ugi=andrew&path=%2F
/apps/accumulo/data/tables/!0/table_info/A000133q.rf
/apps/accumulo/data/tables/+r/root_tablet/A000133t.rf
/apps/accumulo/data/tables/1/default_tablet/F000133r.rf
/user/accumulo/.Trash/Current/apps/accumulo/data/tables/+r/root_tablet/delete+A000133t.rf+F000133s.rf
```

Cluster details are:

```
Hortonworks HDP-2.4.0.0-169
Accumulo    1.7.0.2.4
YARN        2.7.1.2.4
```

Answer (score 3):

First find the bad blocks with:

```
hdfs fsck / | egrep -v '^\.+$' | grep -v eplica
```

then delete the file(s) in the block(s) in question and delete with:

```
hdfs dfs -rm -skipTrash /some/path/to/files
```

As HDFS user run the following:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave

hdfs dfs -rm -R -skipTrash hdfs://servername:8020/apps/accumulo

hadoop fs -mkdir -p /apps/accumulo
hadoop fs -chmod -R 700 /apps/accumulo
hadoop fs -chown -R accumlo:accumulo /apps/accumulo
```

From Ambari restart Accumulo to initialise or run:

```
/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-client/bin/accumulo init
```

and then start with

```
/usr/hdp/current/accumulo-client/bin/start-all.sh
```

Comment: The cluster is back up and running great. Thanks!